# Objective C / Swift version of Java's SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, swift, system-clock

I have a java app that uses `SystemClock.upTimeMillis()`, but now I am trying to replicate the code in Swift (New apple language) for the same app on iOS using the same concepts.

I need to get the clock to reset the seconds to `00` once it reaches 60, and the minutes to carry on going, then the minutes to reset to `00` and hours to carry on going, just to get a clock going (as my app uses a clock like interface).

So I need the Swift / Objective C version of `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`.

Is it possible? or how can I get the clock working the like a normal clock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime]
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProcessInfo/systemUptime

Comment: I get the error of "Use of unresolvedidentifier 'systemUpTime'

Comment: It's systemUp **t** ime and not systemUp **T** ime

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you'll find is probably NSDate which returns and stores a time with sub second accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Swift would be like this:

```
import Foundation

var systemUptime: NSTimeInterval {
    return NSProcessInfo.processInfo().systemUptime
}
```